# AutoScaling Azure PaaS - Functions or RunBooks?

Tags: autoscalemode

I am evaluating pros / cons of Functions Vs RunBooks to Autoscale PaaS Services (HDI, AppService, SQLDB, SQLDataWarehouse, Batch etc).  Scaling should happen based on schedule / workload.

What's the best practice to go forward between both technologies. Any known issues / limitations I should be aware.

Comment: You will find that creating your own auto-scaling to be a hard proposition.  This is because every minute you will need to gather and evaluate a ton of performance data, worry about scale times and cooldown periods, etc.  I suggest CloudMonix @ http://www.cloudmonix.com which can auto-scale most of Azure infrastructure either by time, performance or both

Comment: For Autoscale on App Service, you can rely on the built-in Azure Autoscale which supports both metric and schedule based autoscale with cool downs, etc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-autoscale